# SQL ManyToOne condition

Tags: sql

But if I add one more for my query (that not related to this), for example:

I should get nothing

(but it needs to be workable :D)

Comment: How can I get it? - get what please add an example of what you require as output

Comment: Intersect is one way. EDIT: Just noticed MySql, my bad.

Comment: Sorry @P.Salmon, just added a description

Comment: @Isolated not in mysql it isn't (except conceptually)

Comment: Please add desired outcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a `GROUP BY`, and use `HAVING` to make sure all desired tag_id's are there:

```
SELECT sp.perfume_id
FROM sp_tag_to_perfume sp
WHERE sp.tag_id IN (2070, 127)
GROUP BY sp.perfume_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT sp.tag_id) = 2; -- number of tag_id values (in this case 2070 and 127)
```

Comment: 'make sure all desired tag_id's are there' -is not my reading of the question. OP wants to ignore where a tag is supplied bit NOT there.

Comment: @P.Salmon, that's how I understand "select a single perfume_id that contains ALL tag_ids that I throw to a query", and "if I add one more tag_id for my query (that not related to this perfume_id) [...] I should get nothing".

Answer (score 0):

This can get all the columns and data containing perfume id 199.

```
Select * from sp_tag_to_perfume sp where sp.perfume_id=199;
```

And from tag_id...

```
Select distinct perfume_id from sp_tag_to_perfume sp where sp.tags_id=127;
```

You can use distinct keyword to get unique values of the column.

Comment: I get the impression tag_id should feature somewhere..

Comment: tag_id can use in where clause to apply condition

Comment: Distinct keyword is used to prevent the repitition of perfume_id

Comment: I can't operate perfume_id field in this case, I'm searching for perfumes that contains ALL of the desired tags, without using perfume_id field

Comment: Second query can done this